# How to deploy scrapy project

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to deploy scrapy project. 
But getting error :
My scrapy.cfg file is :

```
[settings]
default = eScraper.settings

[deploy]
url = http://localhost:8680/
project = eScraper
```

And i used this command to deploy : `scrapy deploy default -p eScraper`
But getting error

```
Building egg of eScraper-1369325126
'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Deploying eScraper-1369325126 to http://localhost:8680/addversion.json
Deploy failed: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

I tried changing port also but it didn't worked also i tried using above command with sudo but nothing .....can some one help me.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please first run This command `scrapy server` and then run deploy command on the another terminal...

Comment: In my case, it's `scrapyd`

Answer (score 5):

If you're using lastest version of scrapy (mine 0.24.2) then

```
scrapy server
```

no longer exist, it was moved to separate package called scrapyd
simply run

```
scrapyd
```

to start the service